# Stackoverflow bitcoin giveaway 2019?

Tags: discussion

Good news everyone! [Stackoverflow](https://www.stackoverflow.com) is giving away promotional bitcoins to encourage user participation, and our site has been selected in the program

Some lucky users from [Korean Language stackexchange](https://korean.stackexchange.com/) will have their reputation points converted to bitcoins !!!

**The more you use the site, the better your chances of getting selected**. Needless to say the more points you have the more bitcoins you will get

So everyone, **ask and answer more questions, vote on posts, comment, edit and bring in as many friends into the site as you can**

Looks like they even graduated our site early, and gave us an updated sparkly UI graphics

[image]

Comment: Aha - having read more about the sparkly thing, I realise this is probably an April 1 thing. it's not even April 1 in Korea yet though, let alone here in the UK!

Comment: @topomorto it's real don't miss out

Comment: 4월 1일에도 한강 물은 따뜻할 거에요. 가즈아

Comment: I know it's too late, but maybe using gulim to display Korean would be better.